# Check for whitespace at beginning of string

Tags: php, validation

I need to use `preg_match` to check that only a-z0-9. is used (including full stop(.)). I don't want to replace anything. My problem is that it doesn't notice white space at beginning of a string.

Also, if anyone knows how to check there is no two full stops in a row, I would be very grateful.

What I have so far:

```
("/[^a-z0-9.]+$/",$request)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this without regex using `ltrim'`

`if(ltrim($request) != $request) { // there was whitespace }`

Comment: I don't want to replace anything.

Comment: @ITg - you're not replacing anything here - just checking to see if there was whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: He wants to check whether there are no other chars than .a-z0-9 not if there is no whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: if((!preg_match("/^(?!.*\.{2,}.*$)[a-z0-9.]+$/",$request)) && (ltrim($request) == $request)){
  return true;
  }

Works how I want it to.

Comment: I gave correct answer to person with lowest 'points?' out of the two contributing answers :) Thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?!.*\.{2,}.*$)[a-z0-9.]+$/
```

Explanation

```
^          # start-of-string anchor
(?!        # begin negative look-ahead ("a position not followed by...")
  .*       # anything
  \.{2,}   # a dot, two times or more
  .*       # anything
  $        # the end of the string
)          # end negative lookahead
[a-z0-9.]+ # a-z or 0-9 or dot, multiple times
$          # end-of-string anchor
```

matches

- `"abc"`
- `"abc123"`
- `"abc.123"`

fails

- `" abc"`
- `"abc..123"`
- `"abc!"`

Comment: if((!preg_match("/^(?!.*\.{2,}.*$)[a-z0-9.]+$/",$request)) && (ltrim($request) == $request)){
  return true;
  }

Works how I want it to

Comment: I gave correct answer to person with lowest 'points?' out of the two contributing answers :) Thankyou though !

Comment: @ITg: you gave "correct answer" to somebody who did not answer your question. My answer checks if there are no two full stops in a row, the other one does not.

Comment: But he validated the white space at the beginning. Stop being greedy :P

Comment: @ITg: It does not validate `m..mm` because you said so in your question: *"if anyone knows how to check there is no two full stops in a row"*. And it does not validate whitespace, at least not for me - I'm not sure what you are doing, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
("/[^a-z0-9.]/",$request)
```

Edit - I misread your question.  This will check to see if there are any non `a-z0-9.` characters.

Answer (score 0):

^ inside [] negates characers (changes meaning to "any char except these")

^ outside of [] means "beggining of the string" (same as $ means "end of the string")

So you need something like that:

`("/^[a-z0-9.]+$/",$request)`

If you want to exclude sequences of dots but not single dots you need something bit more complicated:

`preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]|(?<!\\.)\\.)+$/', $request);`